# Python: patching function defined in same module of tested function

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, patch, python-unittest.mock

I have been working with Python's `unittest.mock` library quite a bit, but right now I'm struggling with a use case that may not be approached correctly.

Consider a file `mymodule/code.py` containing the following snippet:

```
def sum():
  pass

def mul():
  pass

def div():
  pass

def get_functions():
  return [sum, mul, div]

def foo():
  functions = get_functions()
  for func in functions:
    func()
```

I want to test the `foo` function, patching the `sum` function, and leaving `mul` and `div` as they are. This is what I tried initially:

```
class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
  @mock.patch('mymodule.code.foo.sum')
  def test_foo(foo_sum_mock):
    foo()
    foo_sum_mock.assert_called_once()
```

However, the patching approach illustrated above does not work. I believe that the `sum` function is patched correctly when loading `mymodule.code.py`, but redefined due to the `def sum()` block.

By reading the official documentation, I also tried to use the `start` and `stop` functions of the `unittest.mock` library as follows:

```
def test_foo():
  patcher = mock.patch('module.code.sum')
  mocked_sum_fun = patcher.start()

  foo()

  mocked_sum_fun.assert_called_once()
  mock_sum_fun.stop()
```

This approach also did not work. I was hoping it would avoid the `sum` function override after the `modules/code.py` file gets loaded.

Is it possible to patch a local function such as `sum`? Or is moving the `sum` function to another file the only option for patching?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

You can mock a function of same module using `mock.patch` and refering this module as `__main__`

**code.py**

```
from unittest.mock import patch

def sum():
    print("called method sum")
    pass

def call_sum():
    sum()

def return_mock():
    print("I'm a mocked method")
    return True

with patch('__main__.sum', return_value=return_mock()) as mock_test:
    call_sum()
    mock_test.assert_called_once() # assure that mocked method was called, not original.
```

You could also use the path of lib (`my_project.code.sum`) instead of `__main__.sum`.

Comment: Getting ModuleNotFoundError,  `'__main__' is not a package`.

Comment: @Velkan check [here](https://www.online-ide.com/1GpsnCFhbf) the code running

Comment: @Velkan in this example, all the code is in just one file.

Comment: It depends heavily on how it's called. I've found somewhere that the reliable way is to use something like `__name__ + '.sum'`.

Comment: @Velkan You are right and the answer is misleading, you might want to edit it.

Answer (score -3):

Generally speaking, you'd want to separate your test code from your production code:

**code.py**

```
def sum():
    pass

def mul():
    pass

def div():
    pass

def get_functions():
    return [sum, mul, div]

def foo():
    functions = get_functions()
    for func in functions:
        func()
```

**code_test.py**

```
import unittest
import mock_test as mock
import code

class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('code.sum')
    def test_foo(self, sum_mock):
        def new_sum_mock(*args, **kwargs):
            # mock code here
            pass
        sum_mock.side_effect = new_sum_mock
        code.foo()
        sum_mock.assert_called_once()
```

But yes, you could place it all into one file:

**code_test.py:**

```
import unittest
import mock_test as mock
import code

def sum():
    pass


def mul():
    pass


def div():
    pass


def get_functions():
    return [sum, mul, div]


def foo():
    functions = get_functions()
    for func in functions:
        func()


class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('code_test.sum')
    def test_foo(self, sum_mock):
        def new_sum_mock(*args, **kwargs):
            # mock code here
            pass

        sum_mock.side_effect = new_sum_mock
        code.foo()
        sum_mock.assert_called_once()
```